# Build a sequence, $a_n$ with $PL=\{0,1,2\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was asked to build a sequence which has exactly three partial limits: $\{0,1,2\}$. Also, for every $n\in\Bbb{N}: \left|a_{n+1} - a_n\right| < 1$

At first I thought about:

$$a_n = \begin{cases} 0 + 1/n &\mbox{if } n = 0 \pmod 4 \\ 
1 + 1/n &\mbox{if } n = 1,3 \pmod 4 \\
2 + 1/n &\mbox{if } n = 2 \pmod 4 \end{cases} $$

But that's works only for one direction. I could split it into $8$ cases but that seems to me an overhead.

How to improve it to answer the question's conditions (with an elegant way)?

Comment: A slight modification works fine: $a_n = \{\frac{1}{n}, 1, 2-\frac{1}{n},1\}$ for $n \equiv 0,1,2,3$ mod $4$ respectively (and  $a_1 = 1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly neater solution that fits the bill (via Winther's comment):
$$
a_n = \begin{cases} 0 + 1/n &\mbox{if } n = 0 \pmod 4 \\ 
1 &\mbox{if } n = 1,3 \pmod 4 \\
2 - 1/n &\mbox{if } n = 2 \pmod 4 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Oh I should have think about it.. Thank you!